# Closed form for $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^n)\mathbb{d}x$

Tags: integration, closed-form

I was wondering if anyone knows a closed form for

$$\mathrm{I} = \int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^n)\mathbb{d}x$$

Preliminary evaluations on Wolfram Alpha seem to yield something like this:

$$\mathrm{I} = k\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac an \right)$$

where $k$ is a proportionality constant, normally $1$, and $a$ is a constant, normally $1$ as well.

Comment: Mathematica gives $$\int_0^\infty \sin x^n dx = \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \sin \frac{\pi}{2n}$$

Comment: I wonder if it could be done as $Im\int_0^{\infty} \exp(i x^n) dx$.

Comment: This question reminds me that I keep meaning to look up the details of the history of this integral. This is just my own speculation here, but I think the convergence of this integral is such a striking and counter-intuitive result that if a closed form value *had not* existed, they would have assigned it a Greek letter and called that a "closed form". :)

Comment: @DavidH: *the convergence of this integral is such a striking and counter-intuitive result* - See [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: **Hint:** Use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) in conjunction with the integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has a closed form

> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(i x^{1/\alpha}) \, \Bbb{d}x = \Gamma(1+\alpha)e^{i\pi\alpha/2}, \quad \alpha \in (0, 1). $$

Applying the substitution $x \mapsto x^{\alpha}$, we can write

$$ I(\alpha) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(ix^{1/\alpha}) \, \Bbb{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{ix} \, \Bbb{d}x, \tag{1} $$

which is much easier to work with.

---

**Complex-analytic method.** Rotate the contour of $\text{(1)}$ by $90^{\circ}$ degrees to have

$$ I(\alpha) = \alpha \int_{0}^{i\infty} z^{\alpha-1} e^{iz} \, dz. $$

This is a standard technique, and we can justify this by applying the Cauchy integration formula to a quadrant contour and then utilizing the [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Then by the substitution $z \mapsto ix$, we have

$$ I(\alpha) = \alpha i^{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x} \, dx = \Gamma(1+\alpha)i^{\alpha}. $$

---

**Real-analytic method.** Since the right-hand side of $\text{(1)}$ exists as improper-integral sense, it follows from the integral version of the [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) that

$$ I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{ix} \, \Bbb{d}x = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{ix}e^{-\epsilon x} \, \Bbb{d}x. \tag{2} $$

Using the formula

$$ \frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}{x^{1-\alpha}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-\alpha}e^{-xu} \, \Bbb{d}u $$

and the Fubini's theorem, we can write

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{ix}e^{-\epsilon x} \, \Bbb{d}x
&= \frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-\alpha}e^{-xu} \, \Bbb{d}u\right) e^{-(\epsilon-i) x} \, \Bbb{d}x \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(u+\epsilon-i) x} \, \Bbb{d}x\right)  u^{-\alpha} \, \Bbb{d}u \\
&= \frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{-\alpha}}{u+\epsilon-i} \, \Bbb{d}u.
\end{align*}

(Notice that we cannot apply the Fubini's theorem directly when $\epsilon = 0$ due to integrability issue. This explains why we are considering a regularized version $\text{(2)}$ of the original integral.)

Taking $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, we have

$$ I(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{1-\alpha} + iu^{-\alpha}}{u^2+1} \, \Bbb{d}u. \tag{3} $$

Using the [beta function identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function), the last integral in $\text{(3)}$ can be computed explicitly as

$$ I(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\left( \frac{1}{\sin(\pi\alpha/2)} + \frac{i}{\cos(\pi\alpha/2)} \right). $$

Finally, from the [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) and the sine double-angle formula we have

$$ I(\alpha) = \Gamma(1+\alpha) e^{i\pi\alpha/2}. $$

Comment: Excellent Solutions!  +1