# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos(tx)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(tx)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

**The original problem is** $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{itx}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx$

My work:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos(tx)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx=-\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos(tx)x^{\alpha-1}de^{-x/\lambda}}=-\lambda t\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\sin(tx)x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx+\lambda (\alpha-1)^2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cos(tx)x^{\alpha-2}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx.$

**Changed**
Can I solve it this way?
Let $y=x(1/\lambda-it)$.
Solve this $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{itx}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\lambda}}dx$. My concern is when $x=\infty$, is $y$ also infinity?

I do not how to continue.

Comment: From your comment on Chinny84's answer, I must ask: What tools _do_ you have? It would be easier and it could save time and effort if you told so in the question. Also, what is the source of this integral? Is it an exercise from a book?

Comment: @mickep. I revised it. Also can you provide a basic book about how to integrate above integral?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** With the help of a simple linear substitution, try to express or rewrite your integral in terms of the famous [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Please see the **changed**

Comment: @Jack: Technically, it will be an oriented, complex infinity. But it can be proven, using complex integration along a certain contour, that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty=\int_0^{z~\infty}.~$ However, doing that defeats the purpose of simplicity. $($Personally, I prefer a symbolic, intuitive approach to a very rigorous one$).$

Comment: What do you mean by **a simple linear substitution**? Change variable($y=x(1/\lambda-it)$)?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, exactly.

Comment: So This is the problem I have. After changing variable, we need the change the upper limit and lower limit of integral. Lower limit is $0$, but how do you define $y$ when $x\rightarrow\infty$? And I do not understand $\int^{z\infty}_{0}$? What is $z\infty$

Comment: @Jack: I already answered. $~z=\dfrac1\lambda-it,~$ and $z~\infty$ is the oriented infinity along the line uniting the origin with *z*.

Comment: Can you provide more details about why $\int_{0}^{\infty}=\int_{0}^{z\infty}$?

Comment: @Jack: Use techniques similar to the ones presented in [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171970) [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729) [posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552654).

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int \cos(tx)x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{e}^{-x/\lambda}dx= \mathcal{Re}\left(\int \mathrm{e}^{itx}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{e}^{-x/\lambda}\right) = \mathcal{Re}\left(i^{\alpha-1}\dfrac{d^{\alpha-1}}{dt^{\alpha-1}}\int \mathrm{e}^{itx}\mathrm{e}^{-x/\lambda}dx\right)
$$
This could be an easier approach.

Comment: I have not been told how to integrate complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the cosine as a sum of two complex exponentials, then simply integrate $\alpha$ times by parts.